Dataframe keyError when trying to loop through a for loop when using .loc
I want to use a dataframe to save data that I'll be using for later. Its structure is like so:



index
name
data




0
A
100


1
B
4012



I have been able to save this to a pkl, and be able to read from this data using df.loc, setting it to the proper coordinates, and then saving that data to a variable in a jupyter notebook. My problem is when I try to write the proper script, which uses a loop to go through the dataframe to find the proper location. The code looks like such:
    str_comp= 'something'
    df= pd.read_pickle(<filepath>)

    data_to_save= None
    for i in df:
        if df.loc[i,'name'] == str_comp:
            data_to_save= df.loc[i,'data']
            continue

When I try running this, I get this error:
415         raise KeyError(key) from err
    416 if isinstance(key, Hashable):
--> 417     raise KeyError(key)
    418 self._check_indexing_error(key)
    419 raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'data'

I've tried df.loc and df.iloc to solve this problem, yet I get the same error effectively every time. I'm not sure what it's asking for, especially since when I do it line by line in a notebook, it works just fine. It's only when I try looping through it like the above, I get this error.
edit: to give the specific traceback-
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 6
      4 if var in dict:
      5     if var1 != 'str':
----> 6         save_to_data(var,"var2")

File ~<filepath to script>/script.py:48, in save_to_data(name, y)
     47 def save_to_data(name,y):
---> 48     data= df_creation(name,y)
     49     data_to_pickle(f"<filepath to data folder/<name of file>.pkl")

File <filepath to script>\script.py:31, in df_creation(name, y)
     data_to_save= None
    for i in df:
    if df.loc[i,'name'] == str_comp:
        data_to_save= df.loc[i,'data']
        continue

File<filepath to directory>\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1183, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   1181     key = tuple(com.apply_if_callable(x, self.obj) for x in key)
   1182     if self._is_scalar_access(key):
-> 1183         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
   1184     return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1185 else:
   1186     # we by definition only have the 0th axis

File <filepath to directory>\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4209, in DataFrame._get_value(self, index, col, takeable)
   4203 engine = self.index._engine
   4205 if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
   4206     # CategoricalIndex: Trying to use the engine fastpath may give incorrect
   4207     #  results if our categories are integers that dont match our codes
   4208     # IntervalIndex: IntervalTree has no get_loc
-> 4209     row = self.index.get_loc(index)
   4210     return series._values[row]
   4212 # For MultiIndex going through engine effectively restricts us to
   4213 #  same-length tuples; see test_get_set_value_no_partial_indexing

File<filepath to directory>\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py:417, in RangeIndex.get_loc(self, key)
    415         raise KeyError(key) from err
    416 if isinstance(key, Hashable):
--> 417     raise KeyError(key)
    418 self._check_indexing_error(key)
    419 raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'name'


Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Post the full error traceback message.

if df.loc[i,'name'] == str_comp: is where it happens. it then retraces back to where get_loc is defined. I'll edit it down and post it to the question as an edit for clarity.

for i in df:  will return the column headers.  this line isn't doing what you expect it is.
You probably want something like for i, _ in df.iterrows(): to get dataframe index labels.  Although, this not the preferred way to interact with a dataframe.

What would be a more proper way of doing this? The datasets that I'm going to need to build off of this code is going to end up being quite large, so if there's a more efficient way to go about doing this particular thing, as I'll need to do it a lot, I'm all ears.
